# Tabitem not getting selected from viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am unable to select the tabitem from viewmodel , i tries with isselected and selectedindex but it still doesn't work.

Viewmodel:

```
      public int _selectedIndex;
    public int SelectedTabIndex
    {
        get { return _selectedIndex; }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedIndex != value)
            {
                _selectedIndex = value;
                //if (RaisePropertyChanged != null)
                    RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedIndex");
            }

        }
    }
```

XAML Code:

```
 <TabItem Header="Fault Code Table" DataContext="{Binding TESTModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" IsEnabled="True" TabIndex="{Binding Path=SelectedTabIndex ,Mode=TwoWay}"  >
                            <StackPanel>
                                <local:FaultCodeTable />    
                            </StackPanel>
                        </TabItem>
```

Comment: Bind to `SelectedIndex`, not `TabIndex` which is an unrelated property. When you use the tab key to cycle through controls in a window, the ordering is governed by the TabIndex assigned to each control -- every control has that property.

Comment: SelectedIndex is not available for tabitem.

Comment: Whoops, sorry, I didn't notice you were binding that on `TabItem` rather than `TabControl`. `TabControl.SelectedIndex` is the index of the selected `TabItem` in that `TabControl`. Is that what you were trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to go to a tabitem which comes under a tabcontrol. is my viewmodel correct ?

Comment: Your viewmodel property looks fine to me. The `TabControl` is responsible for deciding which of its `TabItem`s is selected. If you want to control which `TabItem` is selected, use the `SelectedIndex` or `SelectedItem` property of the `TabControl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bind the `SelectedIndex` property of parent `TabControl` to your source property:

```
<TabControl SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedTabIndex}">...
```

An individual `TabItem` has an `IsSelected` property that you can use to determine whether it's currently selected. It has no concept of any selected index though because it is not an `ItemsControl`.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. and also the property of Tabitem IsSelected changes the property only once.. this is my viewmodel  `private bool _isselected;
        public bool Isselected
        {
            get { return _isselected; }
            set
            {
                _isselected = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("_Isselected");
            }
        }` and this my XAML `<TabItem Header="Fault Code Table"  DataContext="{Binding TESTModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" IsSelected="{Binding Isselected,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  >`

Comment: @SamKing Your public property is named `Isselected`. You pass `"_Isselected"` to `RaisePropertyChanged`, but the property `_Isselected` does not exist. Try passing the actual name of the property.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I have a public property defined in the model `private bool _isselected;
        public bool Isselected
        {
            get { return _isselected; }
            set
            {
                _isselected = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("_Isselected");
            }
        }`

Comment: @SamKing Good luck with your project!